# Background: cover header image with menu always at the bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a header with a full width/height background image. The menu must always be at the very bottom on page load or resize. When scrolling, the menu become sticky at the top when it toutch the screen top.

Something like this: http://www.themarmalade.com/

here's what I got in the moment:

html:

```
<div class="minhaClass">
    <div class="menu-bottom">menu</div>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

css:

```
   div{
    width:100%;
    height:350px;
}
.minhaClass{
    background: url(http://placehold.it/550x350) no-repeat center center;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    /*height:100%;*/
}
.menu-bottom {
    position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 3rem;
line-height: 3rem;
background-color: #5454b9;
color: #fffdfa;
text-align: center;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background: grey;
}
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: inherit;
    top: 0;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var w = $(window);
w.on("scroll", function(){
    if(w.scrollTop() >= 305){
        $('.menu-bottom').addClass('sticky');
    }
    else {
        $('.menu-bottom').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
```

});

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ejv9/80/

Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: it looks like it sticks to me, what's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if this is what you mean, but I think you want the `minhaClass` div to take up 100% of the viewport.

If that is the case add these:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

uncomment out the height in `minhaClass`

```
.minhaClass{
background: url(http://placehold.it/550x350) no-repeat center center;
position: relative;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
height:100%;
```

}

Next the jquery, we need to get the height of the viewport, this can be done using `$( window ).height();`

so your updated jquery will be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var w = $(window);
var b = $( window ).height();
w.on("scroll", function(){
    if(w.scrollTop() >= b){
        $('.menu-bottom').addClass('sticky');
    }
    else {
        $('.menu-bottom').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});
});
```

There is more you can do here to improve it, such as the height `var b` takes into account covers the menu so your menu wont become sticky until you scroll past it to fix that you can subtract the height of the menu div from b by using this `var b = $( window ).height() - $('.menu-bottom').height();`